# Xamarin not found

Tags: c#, tfs, xamarin.ios

I've been having issues with compiling code. The code was running successfully, and I uploaded it to Team Foundation Server. However, when people (including myself) downloaded the code from Team Foundation Server, the code produced the error:

"Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I've got the newest version of Xamarin.Forms.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamlSamples
{
        public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new HelloXamlPage();
        }        
            };
        }
```

Comment: Check the _References_ for the project - is there a valid reference to _Xamarin_?

Comment: There are 3 references for Xamarin: Xamarin.Forms.Core, Xamarin.Forms.Platform & Xamarin.Forms.Xaml. On the properties, they all have Copy Local= False, whereas my local copy has Copy Local= True. How can I fix this? I tried just changing the False to True, but it just switched back.

Comment: Try to restore Xamarin.Forms from Nuget to see whether your issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have enable automatic Package Restore (restore Xamarin.forms) in Visual Studio. Go to Tools--Options--Nuget Package Manager--General, check the items below:

- Allow NuGet to download missing packages
- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio

Comment: Xamarin is not a NuGet package.

Comment: @EvilTak, just double checked, if project can't find Xamarin.Forms will lead this error.

Comment: Blame that on misinformation. This will work if Xamarin.Forms was included as a *NuGet package* in the original project.

Comment: I've updated to the newest version of Xamarin.Forms via Nuget, and it's still not working for me.